why maven-enforcer-plugin always fails even when there are rules
Although I read the maven-enforcer-plugin documentation, running mvn enforcer:enforce always fails.
This is pom.xml taken from the documentation
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.baz</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>foo</name>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <AlwaysPass/>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

This is the execution and output of mvn enforcer:enforce
$ mvn enforcer:enforce
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< com.baz:foo >------------------------
[INFO] Building foo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- enforcer:3.5.0:enforce (default-cli) @ foo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.229 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-08-26T11:19:54Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.5.0:enforce (default-cli) on project foo: No rules are configured. Use the skip flag if you want to disable execution. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Although the rules for maven-enforcer-plugin exist in pom.xml, it fails with No rules are configured. Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

You should not run the goal... you should run mvn verify or alike... If you try to run a goal directly no configuration is taken into account... because the given configuration is only related to the life cycle (verify for example) but not for the goal itself...

@khmarbaise although other answer was accepted, know that you are correct

I guess you need to move the <configuration> out of the <executions>.

That makes the configuration global which includes the command line as well.
